# why are scanf/printf of a string printing different things

Tags: c

I know that this is simple. I tried looking for an answer in stackoverflow before asking but couldn't find an answer.

```
char str[5], new_str[5];
int i, len;

printf("Enter a string: ");
scanf("%s", str);
len = strlen(str);

for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    new_str[i] = str[i];
}

printf("Result: %s", new_str);
```

I get:

```
Enter a string: 1234
Result: 1234╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠1234
```

I know how to do it properly(using malloc) but I am trying to understand why this is output happened.

Comment: "I know how to do it properly ..." No, you don't! Read how C strings are terminated. And limit the number of chars accepted by `scanf` to what is available in the buffer.

Comment: Strings need to be null terminated.  `char str[5]` can only hold 4 characters plus a trailing null.  You're not handling the strings correctly because `12345` has 5 characters so `str` has no null so all hell breaks loose (welcome to 'undefined behaviour' — avoid it like the plague it is).  Also, although you compute `len = strlen(str);`, you never use that value.

Comment: The string is not long enough. You entered 5 characters, so it needs `char str[6];`

Comment: Again STOP DECLARING STUPID CHAR ARRAY SIZES FOR TEXT LINES unless you are on some RAM-retricted embedded system. What possessed you to type '5' instead of, say, '256'???  WHY?

Comment: I forgot about the null character. You can delete the question...

Comment: You would do best to limit the input string: `scanf("%4s", str);` (and test that it worked).  You could also use `printf("Result: %.5s\n", str);` and that would work better.  However, when you enter the overlong string on the input (even just one byte too long), you are not guaranteed anything.  You might be OK, you might not; it is only safe to assume you will not and prevent the overflow.

Comment: @Lee I believe _you_ can delete the question, but most of the rest of us cannot unless it goes through a potentially lengthy voting process. I've voted to close it; if 4 more agree then it gets closed and then we can vote to delete... or you could directly delete.

Comment: This is the second one of these 'I'll just declare a really small array 'cos.... nobody knows' today.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012571/why-does-the-stack-get-corrupted

Comment: @MartinJames: maybe the second one today; certainly not the second one in the history of SO.  I usually 4096 as the size for 'lines' of input, partly for the shock value.  POSIX sets LINE_MAX to 2048, IIRC, which is the minimum length that is acceptable for the longest line that the system accepts.  That said, 256 is a huge step in the right direction (heck, even 80 would be better, though that's a very imperfect value to be using too).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I suspect that most of these are disguised no-effort homework questions.

Comment: ╠ is 0xCC in codepage 437, and [MSVC fills 0xCC to uninitialized memory to help debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714). That means you've accessed uninitialized memory. You can find tons of questions about ╠ and 0xCC here on SO

Answer (score 3):

The variable `new_str` has no `'\0'` symbol at the end of it because it's an array but not a "string".

The call to `printf("%s", new_str);` prints the whole string up to the `'\0'` symbol, which ends a string.

After the input shown, `str` is equivalent to `{"1","2","3","4","5","\0"}` and `new_str` is equivalent to `{"1","2","3","4","5"}` because you only copied 5 symbols. Because of that, `printf` prints other symbols after 12345 (`new_str`) which are in the next cells of memory, up until it does find a null byte.  And that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Probable a good answer. Please format it

Comment: After input how `str` is equivalent to `{"1","2","3","4","5","\0"} `? It has size `5` and you say it has 6 elements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the null terminator to the string.

i.e. add

```
new_str[i] = 0;
```

Before the

```
printf....
```

Anyway perhaps

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
```

and check out the page for `scanf` so as to not overrun the buffer

Comment: More saliently, the `scanf()` should use `%4s` to avoid overflowing the string; then everything would be OK.

Comment: After the loop, `i == 5`... so if he follows your current suggestion of `new_str[i] = 0;`, when considering `char new_str[5];` he's in trouble.

Comment: Agreed with both comments.

Answer (score 0):

You enter `12345` in `str`, no space for `'\0'`,thus giving **UB**.

Restrict input in `str` like this -

```
  scanf("%4s", str);
```

And this loop-

```
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     new_str[i] = str[i];
 }
```

Size of both arrays is `5` but strings in `C` are `null terminated` so this loop should go till `i=4`.

And `new_str[4]='\0';` should be set.